# Transaction Rollback while updating - Junit of DataJPA

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I am working with springboot 2.6.3 and junit5, and writing data jpa unit test cases , i am writing unit test case for update, the test result is success but I am getting transaction rollback, it is not committing to db.

`2022-02-20 19:14:45.183  INFO 19942 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for`

Here is the more details of the logs

`2022-02-20 19:14:19.324  INFO 19942 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2022-02-20 19:14:19.688  INFO 19942 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
2022-02-20 19:14:19.689  WARN 19942 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2022-02-20 19:14:19.725  INFO 19942 --- [           main] c.u.r.SystemUserRepositoryTest           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-20 19:14:22.366  INFO 19942 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-20 19:14:22.631  INFO 19942 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 241 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-20 19:14:23.634  INFO 19942 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=2d3b8fac-a232-3295-b483-ac7040d3c59c
2022-02-20 19:14:25.314  INFO 19942 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-02-20 19:14:26.856  INFO 19942 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-02-20 19:14:27.118  INFO 19942 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-02-20 19:14:27.326  INFO 19942 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.3.Final
2022-02-20 19:14:27.868  INFO 19942 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-02-20 19:14:28.538  INFO 19942 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-02-20 19:14:31.940  INFO 19942 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-02-20 19:14:31.974  INFO 19942 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-20 19:14:35.704  WARN 19942 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-02-20 19:14:41.385  INFO 19942 --- [           main] c.u.c.UserManagementSecurityConfigurer   : The password of the restful service is $2a$10$ao9M1pLRtM06lPpRzU1SuOoVeESDiCOD/npBkFyesZN8i2P7t.F.y
2022-02-20 19:14:41.920  INFO 19942 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4ba32242, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@10ecf244, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@628d6320, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@64ef9b9a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@5a0b925a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@a703934, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@369f85c6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@581f1f40, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@174e5929, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@63ead376, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6d21a69f]
2022-02-20 19:14:42.461  INFO 19942 --- [           main] c.u.r.SystemUserRepositoryTest           : Started SystemUserRepositoryTest in 26.565 seconds (JVM running for 29.504)
2022-02-20 19:14:42.610  INFO 19942 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@3f390d63 testClass = SystemUserRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.usermgmtservice.repositories.SystemUserRepositoryTest@1cc5d8a9, testMethod = updateSystemUserTest@SystemUserRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@74a6a609 testClass = SystemUserRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.usermgmtservice.UserMgmtApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4808bc9b, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@13df2a8c, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@e25951c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@2dc9b0f5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@7bf3a5d8, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@22635ba0], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@32c114d9]; rollback [true]
Hibernate: select systemuser0_.system_user_id as system_u1_1_, systemuser0_.activated_dt as activate2_1_, systemuser0_.created_by as created_3_1_, systemuser0_.created_dt as created_4_1_, systemuser0_.email_address as email_ad5_1_, systemuser0_.email_verification_otp_code as email_ve6_1_, systemuser0_.email_verification_otp_code_generated_dt as email_ve7_1_, systemuser0_.email_verification_otp_code_verified_status as email_ve8_1_, systemuser0_.first_nm as first_nm9_1_, systemuser0_.last_modified_by as last_mo10_1_, systemuser0_.last_modified_dt as last_mo11_1_, systemuser0_.last_nm as last_nm12_1_, systemuser0_.mobile_nbr as mobile_13_1_, systemuser0_.mobile_nbr_otp_code as mobile_14_1_, systemuser0_.mobile_nbr_otp_code_generated_dt as mobile_15_1_, systemuser0_.mobile_nbr_otp_code_verified_status as mobile_16_1_, systemuser0_.password as passwor17_1_, systemuser0_.registered_dt as registe18_1_, systemuser0_.status as status19_1_, systemuser0_.user_role_id as user_ro20_1_ from system_user systemuser0_ where systemuser0_.email_address=?
Hibernate: select userrole0_.user_role_id as user_rol1_2_0_, userrole0_.created_by as created_2_2_0_, userrole0_.created_dt as created_3_2_0_, userrole0_.description as descript4_2_0_, userrole0_.last_modified_by as last_mod5_2_0_, userrole0_.last_modified_dt as last_mod6_2_0_, userrole0_.role_nm as role_nm7_2_0_, userrole0_.status as status8_2_0_ from user_role userrole0_ where userrole0_.user_role_id=?
Before -> the opsystemuser is not empty and its firstname is David , systemUserId = 7, status = R
Hibernate: update system_user set status=?, mobile_nbr_otp_code_verified_status=?, email_verification_otp_code_verified_status=?, last_modified_dt=?, activated_dt=? where system_user_id=?
Hibernate: select systemuser0_.system_user_id as system_u1_1_, systemuser0_.activated_dt as activate2_1_, systemuser0_.created_by as created_3_1_, systemuser0_.created_dt as created_4_1_, systemuser0_.email_address as email_ad5_1_, systemuser0_.email_verification_otp_code as email_ve6_1_, systemuser0_.email_verification_otp_code_generated_dt as email_ve7_1_, systemuser0_.email_verification_otp_code_verified_status as email_ve8_1_, systemuser0_.first_nm as first_nm9_1_, systemuser0_.last_modified_by as last_mo10_1_, systemuser0_.last_modified_dt as last_mo11_1_, systemuser0_.last_nm as last_nm12_1_, systemuser0_.mobile_nbr as mobile_13_1_, systemuser0_.mobile_nbr_otp_code as mobile_14_1_, systemuser0_.mobile_nbr_otp_code_generated_dt as mobile_15_1_, systemuser0_.mobile_nbr_otp_code_verified_status as mobile_16_1_, systemuser0_.password as passwor17_1_, systemuser0_.registered_dt as registe18_1_, systemuser0_.status as status19_1_, systemuser0_.user_role_id as user_ro20_1_ from system_user systemuser0_ where systemuser0_.email_address=?
After -> the opsystemuser is not empty and its firstname is David , systemUserId = 7, status = R
2022-02-20 19:14:45.183  INFO 19942 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@3f390d63 testClass = SystemUserRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.usermgmtservice.repositories.SystemUserRepositoryTest@1cc5d8a9, testMethod = updateSystemUserTest@SystemUserRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@74a6a609 testClass = SystemUserRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.usermgmtservice.UserMgmtApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4808bc9b, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@13df2a8c, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@e25951c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@2dc9b0f5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@7bf3a5d8, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@22635ba0], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]
2022-02-20 19:14:45.299  INFO 19942 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-20 19:14:45.308  INFO 19942 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-02-20 19:14:45.341  INFO 19942 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.`

Here is my repository code

```
public interface SystemUserRepository extends JpaRepository<SystemUser, Long> {
    

    @Modifying
    @Query("update SystemUser su set su.status=?2, su.mobileNoOtpCodeVerifiedStatus=?3, su.emailVerificationOtpCodeVerifiedStatus=?4, su.lastModifiedDate = ?5 ,su.activatedDate = ?6 where su.systemUserId = ?1")
    public int update(long systemUserId, String status, int otpVerificationCodeVerifiedStatus,
            int emailVerificationCodeVerifiedStatus, Date lastModifiedDate, Date activatedDate);
    
    public Optional<SystemUser> findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);

}
```

test code

```
@Test
@Transactional
void updateSystemUserTest() {
        String emailAddress = "test@gmail.com";
        Date date = new Date();
        Optional<SystemUser> opSystemUser = this.systemUserRepository.findByEmailAddress(emailAddress);
        
        SystemUser systemUser = opSystemUser.get();
        System.out.println("Before -> the opsystemuser is not empty and its firstname is "+systemUser.getFirstName()+" , systemUserId = "+ systemUser.getSystemUserId()+", status = " + systemUser.getStatus());
        
        int updatedRecords = this.systemUserRepository.update(systemUser.getSystemUserId(), "A", 1, 1, date, date);
        
        opSystemUser = this.systemUserRepository.findByEmailAddress(emailAddress);
        systemUser = opSystemUser.get();
        System.out.println("After -> the opsystemuser is not empty and its firstname is "+systemUser.getFirstName()+" , systemUserId = "+ systemUser.getSystemUserId()+", status = " + systemUser.getStatus());
        assertEquals(1, updatedRecords);
        

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

you also need to add @Rollback(false) with @Test, @Transactional